# Is the Supreme Court's in-house citation style manual publicly available?

Tags: us-supreme-court, legal-writing, legal-citation

SCOTUS uses a distinct in-house citation style which, although it has a lot in common with the *Bluebook*, is not the same (differing in key places) and is as far as I know unique.

Is the citation style manual used in house for SCOTUS publicly available? Either because the Court has published it, or via FOI requests? It is probably possible to reverse engineer the citation rules from the Opinions of the Court, but do we have the guide for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A version republishing the Reporter's style guide is [available on SSRN](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2758862) and for purchase on Amazon.

It was edited in 2016, [purportedly based on a 2013 copy of the Court's private style guide that the editor (Jack Metzler) somehow obtained](https://www.nelsonmullins.com/idea_exchange/insights/the-scrivener-is-your-writing-good-enough-for-the-supreme-court-u-s-supreme-court-style-guide).

The Court's internal style guide may have evolved since then.

Comment: Didn't know about the free version on SSRN. Nice find!

Answer (score 2):

The Reporter of Decisions' style guide is available [on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/099111633X).